# Count of Mismatch records based on date colum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables.Data are moving from source table into target table.

```
create table source_table(sno number,pick_date date);

create table target_table(sno number,pick_Date date)

select * from source_table

sno  pick_date
1   12-JAN-23
3   13-JAN-23
5   14-JAN-23
6   14-JAN-23
7   14-Jan-23
2   13-JAN-23


    select * from target_table

    Sno  Pick_date
    1   12-JAN-23
    2   13-JAN-23
    5   14-JAN-23
```

I want to find the missing records count based on the pick_date column between two tables.

```
Result

Pick_date  Count
13-jan-23  1 
14-jan-23  2
```

only one record is missed in the target table for the pick_date 13th Jan 2023 and two records are missed in target table on 14th jan 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.

Source data:

```
SQL> with
  2  source_table (sno, pick_date) as
  3    (select 1, date '2023-01-12' from dual union all
  4     select 3, date '2023-01-13' from dual union all
  5     select 5, date '2023-01-14' from dual union all
  6     select 6, date '2023-01-14' from dual union all
  7     select 7, date '2023-01-14' from dual union all
  8     select 2, date '2023-01-13' from dual
  9    ),
 10  target_Table (sno, pick_date) as
 11    (select 1, date '2023-01-12' from dual union all
 12     select 2, date '2023-01-13' from dual union all
 13     select 5, date '2023-01-14' from dual
 14    )
```

Query uses `minus` set operator to find rows that are missing in the target table and counts number of rows per each date:

```
 15  select pick_date, count(*)
 16  from (select sno, pick_date from source_table
 17        minus
 18        select sno, pick_date from target_Table
 19       )
 20  group by pick_date;

PICK_DATE    COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
13.01.2023          1
14.01.2023          2

SQL>
```

---

If there's no unique column in these tables and you don't feel like typing 10 different columns, "create" unique value per each pick date with `row_number` analytic function; then repeat code I already posted:

```
 15  st as
 16    (select pick_date, row_number() over (partition by pick_date order by sno) rn
 17     from source_table
 18    ),
 19  tt as
 20    (select pick_date, row_number() over (partition by pick_date order by sno) rn
 21     from target_table
 22    )
 23  select pick_date, count(*)
 24  from (select rn, pick_date from st
 25        minus
 26        select rn, pick_date from tt
 27       )
 28  group by pick_date;

PICK_DATE    COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
13.01.2023          1
14.01.2023          2

SQL>
```

Comment: is it possible to find the mismatch without sno column in the minus query?Because my table having more then 10 columns.

Comment: You don't have to type all 10 columns; unique identifier (which is what SNO is, right?) is enough.

Comment: i checked my production table, there is not unique column.Some duplicate values are present in the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use the `FULL OUTET JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT COALESCE(S.PICK_DATE, T.PICK_DATE) AS PICK_DATE,
       COUNT(*) AS CNT
  FROM SOURCE_TABLE S
  FULL OUTER JOIN TARGET_TABLE T
    ON T.PICK_DATE = S.PICK_DATE
   AND T.SNO = S.SNO
 WHERE T.PICK_DATE IS NULL OR S.PICK_DATE IS NULL
GROUP BY COALESCE(S.PICK_DATE, T.PICK_DATE)
```